# ERROR: dependency ‘proxy’ is not available for package ‘quanteda’

Tags: r

```
install.packages("quanteda")
```

resulted the above mentioned error.

I couldn't find the package in Packages Tab.
What can be done?

Comment: Have you tried running `install.packages("proxy")` before running `install.packages("quanteda")`? If installing `proxy` fails, what is the error you get for it?

Comment: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘proxy’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`

Answer (score 3):

The 'proxy' package requires R version 3.3.2 or later. Have you tried upgrading R?

From [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proxy/index.html):

> Depends:  R (≥ 3.3.2)

Comment: Actually I saw it and just trying to (will update).

I don't understand how old packages with dependency in 'proxy' can run (as 'recommenderlab'), as I saw in this tutorial from 2014:

https://ashokharnal.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/using-recommenderlab-for-predicting-ratings-for-movielens-data/

Comment: As I suspected - that was the problem.